# Radix conversion issue

Tags: binary

I have a funny radix conversion problem. I'm programming in a language called Solidity. It's very primitive and doesn't have many of the standard string and math operators that you'd expect in other languages.

I am passing the following data to my program:

"123456"

This compound string presents inside my program as three bytes (native `byte` types):

"12", "34" and "56"

I have successfully converted these strings to:

18, 52 and 86 (stored natively as `uint` types)

My question is this: how the hell do I convert 18, 52 and 86 to 123456 (i.e. a `uint` with the value one-hundred-and-twenty-three-thousand-four-hundred-and-fifty-six)?

Comment: I should say that I could ask my users to enter "0x1e240" instead of "123456". But as most of my users do not understand hex (nor do I, it seems...), I need to do it this way...

Comment: Why ask this here rather than on the support forum for Solidity?

Comment: Fair comment, but I just thought first principles maths brains would be much quicker at this conversion gymnastics.

Comment: But the maths brains here have no idea what you can and can't do in Solidity.

Comment: Yeah. It's tricky in Solidity, because there are no decimals. Only unsigned ints... And uints are 256 bits long by default!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
//msg.data="0x1234"

uint i=0;
uint dec=0;
for (i = 0; i < msg.data.length; i++) {
        byte e=msg.data[msg.data.length-i-1];
        uint f=uint(e);
        f=((f/16)*10)+(f%16);
        dec+=(f*(100**i));
}

//dec now contains the `uint` 1234
```

Comment: Wow! [Binary coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). I haven't seen that since the 80s.